# Electron's dialog has "GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged." warning on Ubuntu

Tags: electron

Research online says I need to pass the parent to the dialog to prevent this message from showing up. But passing my `mainWindow` (from main.js) doesn't fix this.

This warning interrupts the flow of my app, for reasons I won't get into. Mainly, I am desperately in need of a way to get rid of this message. Alternatively, an other option other thank Electron's `dialog` to show message windows, as well as open and save dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/12423

It looks like there is a way to use `<input>` instead of `dialog`. Per BATMAH69's repsonse this should do:

```
<input type="file" style="display:none" />
```

I haven't tried it myself yet but at least now we know it's an electron issue. In the same thread above it claims updating electron should also resolve it. Hope it helps!